# Simulating traffic through Sumo and Open map

Tags: python, simulator

When I am trying to simulate the traffic in sumo , i am getting the following error :

[image]

I have tried every possible thing .....to remove this error.

Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try quotation marks

```
python "C:\Program Files (x86)\DLR\Sumo\tools\randomTrips.py" -n map.net.xml -e 100
```

Comment: Even after using the double quotes around path, I am getting the same error !

Comment: Exactly the same error with the missing file name being `C:\Program`? That is very strange. I just double checked and it works here. Which shell and which python version do you use?

Comment: Just one more remark, here the directory is called `C:\Program Files (x86)` with an additional space.

Comment: I am using python version 3.5.1 . When I use those quotes my screen looks like this - http://i.imgur.com/hRZQbTU.jpg?1

Comment: That's a very different error. And it is because of Python 3, try with Python 2.7 instead or use the script from a recent nightly build / svn checkout of sumo.

Comment: It Worked!! Thanks a Lot ! After I installed Python 2.7.9 version . What was wrong with the version 3.5 .Do you have hands over Sumo Simulator for Vehicular ad-hoc network -http://www.dlr.de/ts/en/desktopdefault.aspx/tabid-9883/16931_read-41000/

Comment: Glad it helped, please mark the answer as accepted then. Python syntax changed in some places between Python 2 and 3 https://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#changed-syntax and Sumo is (or rather was) not updated in all the right places. And yes I am affiliated with Sumo.